# RecyclerView: disable scroll to the end after move first item to end

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

If first item moved to the end of list, recyler scrolled to the end. But, if second element moved to the end -- in this case nothing happens. I want disable scrolling for first case for uniform behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try setup `RecyclerView` adapter like this:

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        if (positionStart == 0) {
            recycler.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution than I could find is override `onLayoutChildren` for `LayoutManager`

```
override fun onLayoutChildren(
            recycler: RecyclerView.Recycler?,
            state: RecyclerView.State?
        ) {
            val state1 = onSaveInstanceState()
            super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state)
            onRestoreInstanceState(state1)
        }
```

Looks like the root of the problem in `androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager#updateAnchorFromChildren`